# RF 433MHz - RXB12 vs XY-MK-5V

Tags: rf, 433mhz

Anybody knows the difference between these RF receivers?
I have a project and I am not able to work with RXB12.
It is not receiving my transmitter.

Comment: Add links to both RX datasheets. I'm not going to search for them myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The electrical interface of both receivers is identical. If have changed back and forth between both models in a couple of Arduino circuits. The RXB12 is strongly superior in quality. It is a superhet whereas the XY-MK-5V is just a analog resonator combined with an op amp. The RXB is also much better, if there is RF noise due to its better signal filtration.